# C Library requires -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

Tags: 14.04, make, configure

I've installed binutils 2.24 and gcc 4.8.3 on a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
I'm trying to install a 32-bit MIPS machine simulator called SYS161.
When I run the following:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/os161/tools mibseb
```

I get the following warning:

```
Checking size of off_t... bogus  
Your C library requires -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64.  
Please ask your vendor to provide a reasonable default environment.
```

Subsequently when I run make, I get the following error:

```
error: unknown type name uint32_t  
error: unknown type name uint64_t
```

Could someone tell me how to fix the error?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to take it up with the authors of the program.

Comment: I agree with @psusi. Whenever I have tried to port programs that need it, to compile under linux I have had to add "#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64" to force the loading of the LFS (Large File System) libraries in the compile.

Comment: @DougSmythies the problem appears to be in my version of glibc which is 2.19. I think you need 2.20 and above to support LFS.

Comment: I wouldn't know, as I do not have eglibc installed, but it works fine even on my 12.04 server with build essentials and libc stuff.

Comment: OK, thanks. I know the problem is with the glibc. _FILE_OFFSET_BITS is not defined in the features.h file. I'm going to ask another question related to that.

Comment: @user137481, the program you are compiling has to define it if it wants support for large files.  Hence why I said you need to take it up with the authors of the program since they seem to have added a check to notice it is needed, and foolishly decided to complain instead of setting the #define.

Comment: @psusi thank you for responding. It was my mistake. I found out that it was just a warning. The failure was due to the errors with the uint32_t and uint64_t. The include headers were missing from some of the source files. I edited those files to include the headers and it then compiled.